# Flashvars don't get registered in AS3 via SWFObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashvars

I'm trying to load a URL/GET variable into a FlashVar to be used in AS3. It just traces back in AS3 as undefined.

Here is my JS ($_GET['building'] is set to something and echos out correctly):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/swfobject.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">    
    <?php if(isset($_GET['building'])){ ?>
                var flashvars = { building: '_<?php echo $_GET['building']; ?>' };
            <?php } else { ?>
                var flashvars = {  };
            <?php } ?>
            var params = {};
            var attributes = {};
            swfobject.embedSWF("PlanEventTool_cs5-1.swf", "flashContent", "900", "700", '9.0.0', '<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
```

And my AS3:

```
var allFlashVars:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
buildingString = String(allFlashVars['building']);
trace(buildingString);
```

Been looking at this for a while and I'm sure I'm missing something small.

Any ideas?

Rendered JS:

```
var flashvars = { };
flashvars.building = "_grandstand"; 
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
var flashObj = "PlanEventTool_cs5-1.swf?t=" + new Date().getTime(); // anti-cahce
swfobject.embedSWF(flashObj, "flashContent", "900", "700", '9.0.0', 'expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<object width="900" height="700" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="PlanEventTool_cs5-1.swf?t=1334695440505" id="flashContent" style="visibility: visible;"><param name="flashvars" value="building=_grandstand"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="AllowNetworking" value="all"></object>
```

Comment: Also you are not using any form of anti-caching so that may also be an issue.

Comment: Here's the rendered HTML. I've tried in different browsers/sessions so it shouldn't be caching.

Comment: Sorry I meant the full document not just the object. More concerned about if this line did what it was supposed to var flashvars = { building: '_<?php echo $_GET['building']; ?>' };

Comment: Done! Rendered code can be seen above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure $_GET['building'] exists then the problem is probably with the SWF being cached.
Also I would neaten up your code a tad

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/swfobject.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
     var flashvars = {  };
    <?php
      if(isset($_GET['building'])){ 
        echo 'flashvars.building = ' . $_GET['building'] . ';';
      }
     ?>
     var params = {};
     var attributes = {};
     var flashObj = "PlanEventTool_cs5-1.swf?t=" + new Date().getTime(); // anti-cache
     swfobject.embedSWF(flashObj , "flashContent", "900", "700", '9.0.0', '<?php echo site_url(); ?>js/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
```

Comment: No dice, same problem. I put my rendered code in my question.

Comment: @adamzwakk Check again, this answer, I have done little correction.

Comment: @Engineer Still nothing. Flash traces it back as "undefined"

Comment: @adamzwakk  again please post the full HTML rendered page.

Comment: @The_asMan yes,the `copy-paste` sometime makes problems ;)

Comment: @adamzwakk Ok I see it now. Everything looks good to me. Try putting a break point on this line buildingString = String(allFlashVars['building']); and then examine the variable "allFlashVars" and see if "building" is a property on that object.

Comment: No idea how this worked, but for some reason the t variable (as in the cache time) got sent to AS3.  So I added the building var to the url string on the swf and it worked. Like this: var flashObj = "/flash/PlanEventTool_cs5-1.swf?building=_<?php echo $_GET['building']; ?>&t=" + new Date().getTime(); // anti-cache

Comment: @adamzwakk Using the query is fine. But I am still stumped about the other method. Maybe it's because you have an "_" underscore in front of it. "_grandstand" The leading underscore with sockets has a very specific meaning with sockets and maybe it might be messing it up here.

Answer (score 0):

Really weird.

I checked your code and there are no errors.

Have you deleted your browser's cache (with your html page closed of course)?

Maybe try Event `FRAME_CONSTRUCTED` or timer, what happens if you delay the code?